# Clothes on character deform when posing

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I've been trying to rig this character I made, but his sleeves keep clipping into his arms. I tried using the weight paint with no luck, although I'm new to blender so I'm probably just not doing it right. If anyone could take a look and help me, it'd be greatly appreciated!

File download:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pwAWNtHNoZQqR0a16x20eeXyXb78do0y/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bring some corrections in *Weight Paint* mode, because as we can see, some bones have influence on this part of your mesh while they should not, so activate a brush with the *Blend* mode > *Substract* and the *2D Falloff* option enabled.

Also, in the *Armature* modifier, enable the *Preserve Volume* option.

Perhaps you should also reconsider 2 things: You have a lot of faces, maybe you've applied a Subsurf modifier, was it necessary? I think it would simplify your work to keep a small amount of faces. Also, your armature rest pose should be a T pose, it would help when you parent the mesh to the armature, but to do that you need to modify the armature in *Edit* mode, then reparent the mesh.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton for the detailed response! It's already working better than before, its a good thing I always make backups before applying modifiers..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunally there's a bit less Information in your question and - AFAIS - not any object in your uploaded file?
So a real general answer...

If you are starting with parenting, maybe you're looking for Parenting with armatures?
[Creating Bones for Rigging in Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9tpWUXzV488)

Maybe the problem is cutting in cloths in ellbow and popliteal?
Then IMHO the better solution is using Cloth physics.
A workaround will be using additional bones for sensitive parts.

You can learn much about using weight paint on different bones, if you import a [Make Human](http://www.makehumancommunity.org/) character (I'm using collada to import) and study the dependicies...

I hope it helps.